# Codeigniter insert not working Database error occured

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have following code tried out.

```
    class Vendor extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function vendor_add(){
          $this->load->helper('url');
          $this->load->view('header');
          $this->load->view('sidebar');
          $this->load->view('add_vendor');
          $this->load->view('footer');
    }
        public function save(){
            $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
            $this->load->model('Save_vendor');
            $vendor_data = array(
                        'ven_name'=> $this->input->post['firstName'],
                        'ven_shop'=>$this->input->post['companyName'],
                        'ven_email_id'=>$this->input->post['email'],
                        'ven_contactno'=>$this->input->post['contactno'],
                        'ven_othercontactno'=>$this->input->post['contactno2'],
                        'ven_commission'=>$this->input->post['assigncommission'],
                        'ven_accname'=>$this->input->post['bankaccname'],
                        'ven_accountno'=>$this->input->post['bankaccno'],
                        'ven_ifsccode'=>$this->input->post['ifsccode'],
                        'ven_type'=>$this->input->post['optionsRadios']
                    );

            $this->Save_vendor->vendor_insertdata($vendor_data);

            redirect(base_url().'/vendor/vendor_add');
        }
     }

/* Model File */

     class Save_vendor extends CI_Model{
        public function vendor_insertdata($vendor_data){
        $this->db->insert('tbl_vendor',$vendor_data);
    }

/* VIew FIle */
    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">

            <!-- END SAMPLE PORTLET CONFIGURATION MODAL FORM-->

            <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
            <h3 class="page-title">
            Add Vendor <small> Add New Vendor</small>
            </h3>


             <div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-12">

                           <div class="portlet-body form">
                        <?php echo base_url();?>
                              <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
                              <form action="<?php echo base_url("index.php/Vendor/save") ?>" class="horizontal-form" method="post">
                                 <div class="form-body">
                                    <h3 class="form-section">Add Vendor</h3>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="radio-list">

                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="1" value="1" checked> Shop Vendor </label>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="2" value="2"> Vendor </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <!--/span-->
                                      <div class="col-md-4">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">Vendor Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                              <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" name="firstName">

                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-4">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">Company/Shop/Business Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                              <input type="text" id="companyName" class="form-control" name="companyName" >
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-4">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">Email Id<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                              <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                         <div class="col-md-3">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">Contact No<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                              <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" name="contactno" >

                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-3">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">2nd Contact No</label>
                                              <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" name="contactno2">

                                          </div>
                                       </div>

                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">PIN Code<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                             <input type="text" id="pincode" class="form-control" name="pincode" >


                                          </div>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="col-md-3">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">Assign Commision %<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                               <input type="text" id="assigncommission" class="form-control" name="assigncommission">


                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">BANK Account Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                               <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" name="bankaccname" >


                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                          <div class="col-md-3">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">Account Number<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                               <input type="text" id="bankaccno" class="form-control" name="bankaccno" >
                                             </div>
                                       </div>
                                          <div class="col-md-3">
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="control-label">IFSC Code<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                               <input type="text" id="ifsccode" class="form-control" name="ifsccode">
                                             </div>
                                       </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="form-actions right">
                                                                 <button type="submit" class="btn yellow-crusta"> Add Vendor</button>
                                         </div>
                              </form>
        </div>
                      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- END CONTENT -->
    </div>
<!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Above code but it will give an error Database error occured. Column name not be null. I am beginner in codeigniter please any suggestions for it.

I want to add data in my database.but it is not working.

Comment: Column name not be null means u need to pass all input or ALTER table and make them allowed null

Answer (score 1):

Check your table "tbl_vendor" in which you are inserting values. One or more field is defined as NOT NULL means it will not accept empty value. You have to pass value to that field which is marked as NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Codeigniter Query Builder reference](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) first. You're making big mistakes. Your code should be like below:

```
$vendor_data = array(
                        'ven_name'=> $this->input->post['firstName'],
                        'ven_shop'=>$this->input->post['companyName'],
                        'ven_email_id'=>$this->input->post['email'],
                        'ven_contactno'=>$this->input->post['contactno'],
                        'ven_othercontactno'=>$this->input->post['contactno2'],
                        'ven_commission'=>$this->input->post['assigncommission'],
                        'ven_accname'=>$this->input->post['bankaccname'],
                        'ven_accountno'=>$this->input->post['bankaccno'],
                        'ven_ifsccode'=>$this->input->post['ifsccode'],
                        'ven_type'=>$this->input->post['optionsRadios']
                    );

                    $this->db->insert('your_table_name', $vendor_data);
```